# C++ Builder Tokyo 10.2.3 FMX Android application crash if I dont click on Next button on virtual keyboard

Tags: android, firemonkey, c++builder, virtual-keyboard

I use C++ Builder Tokyo 10.2.3 and trying to do something very simple on Android like typing some text into an Edit box.

If I press Next or Done key on virtual keyboard everything is fine.
If I press an Exit Button to go back the previous form it looks it is fine but then if I press Android Back button application crash.

It took me hours to identify the problem but couldn't find any solution but trying to disable all other objects when user clicks in an Edit box and enable them if user click on Next..

It seems to me a bug but need to make sure before report it to Embarcadero.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and a solution. In short, there is a bug in C++ Builder Tokyo 10.2.3 as if virtual keyboard on Android hide/close because of focus change on a form virtual keyboard doesn't take it as it is hidden properly.. FormVirtualKeyboardHidden working fine but I don't know somehow application crashes. 
So, the solution is to using platform services. Just hide the keyboard manually on FormFocusChanged event.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormFocusChanged(TObject *Sender)
{
    di_IFMXVirtualKeyboardService  VirtualKeyboardService;
    if(TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXVirtualKeyboardService), &VirtualKeyboardService))
    {
       VirtualKeyboardService->HideVirtualKeyboard();
    }
}
```